# Torque on a wire loop from straight wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics, torque

[image]

I need to show that the torque on this wire loop is

$$N = \frac{\mu_0}{\pi} 2abdII' \frac{(b^2+d^2)\sin(\theta)}{b^4+d^4-2b^2d^2\cos(2\theta)}$$

The where $\theta$, is the angle between the loop and the wire (it can rotate about the dottet line).

I know that generally
$$N = I'AB\sin(\theta)$$

$A$ being the area, and $B$ being the magnetic field.

And also that the magnetic field from an infinite wire is
$$B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$$

I also found the distance to the closest side of the loop to be
$$r_1^2 = d^2+b^2-2db\cos(\theta)$$
And the distance to the furthest to be $$r_2^2=d^2+b^2+2db\cos(\theta)$$

I tried to find the flux through the wire

$$\Phi = \int_{r_1}^{r_2}(\frac{\mu_0 I}{2 \pi r}) (2a) dr$$

But that just gives me
$$ \Phi = \frac{\mu_0 I a}{\pi r} ln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})$$

I must have understood something. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I would say that you need to add up the forces of the infinite wired on the four wire segments of the loop.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. Will the two segments orthogonal to the infinite wire experience any force, since they are also orthogonal to the magnetic field?

Comment: Yes they will - current perpendicular to a magnetic field. The two forces will cancel (no _net_ force - by symmetry) but there _would_ be a torque about a vertical axis due to the vertical wire elements. But if you constrain the loop to rotate about a horizontal axis, the vertical elements don't play a role, I suppose.